# type="number" on webview doesn't show numeric keyboard

Tags: android, webview

I have a webview with input fields with attribute type="number", according to docs this should open numeric keyboard. I just get qwerty like with the rest of fields.

Does this need additional development effort? Or is it the device maybe? (I'm using Galaxy S2, Android 4.0)?

Answer (score 0):

My experience on keyboards is about a year old, but back then webview didn't report those fields as numbers to the IME, it reported them as web fields.  Which were treated as text.  The only ones it reported as a different type were passwords.